# Docked panels layout

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panels, dockpanel

In winforms I am trying to setup 4 panels docked: top, left, right and middle.  But when I dock the top and try to dock another panel on the left, that left panel overlays the top panel..Am I doing something wrong there? is there another way of docking several panels?

Comment: WinForms does not have a dock panel control by default. So, please be more specific on which vendor's docking library you are using when asking such questions.

Comment: @LexLi winforms has a panel control, which I would like to dock(it's a property attribute) to my form. not using anything external 3rd party libraries now if you know of one that you recommend and swear by then I'd be more than glad to take a look at it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to be careful to not drop the panels into any of the other panels before selecting their docking property, or they will assume that the panel they were dropped into is their parent.

I created the setup you see below by simply using 4 panels, each one dropped individually and then assigned the correct docking attribute. I made sure when I dropped them to drop them in space that was currently not used by any existing panels.

I'd assume this is what you are after, correct?

[image]

Comment: yes! this is exactly what I am looking to do, now the left, middle and right would grow right? so if i maximize the window they are all stretched out? what I am trying to accomplish is something like itunes for example it has the top a middle for songs and left and right panels.  thanks now how do i get this on mine? hehe

Comment: Just depends on your setup, as you most likely have something additional on your form that is causing issues. Have you tried to create what you see here?

Comment: unbelievable it worked, for some reason it worked.  I created a new form with nothing on it and just started adding panels in every position that I wanted and docked them all and it work! thank u for your patience in explaining this :)